# Is there a graph product that is multiplicative in independence number?

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

I know that Stable set cannot be approximated to constant factor. I saw a simple proof using OR product sometime back. I am unable to recall it. If anyone here knows what I am talking about could help fill my memory, that will be helpful.

Is there a graph product $\cdot$ such that $\alpha(G\cdot G)=\alpha(G)^2$ for all  graphs $G$ and $G\cdot G$ the product of $G$ with itself?

I only need an answer to inapproximability to constant factor and I believe there is a one step proof for this.

If we had such a product, then we have $\alpha(G\cdot G\cdot\cdots \cdot G\cdot G)=\alpha(G)^k$. If $\alpha(G\cdot G\cdot\cdots \cdot G\cdot G)$ can be approximated to constant factor $\sigma>0$, then $\alpha(G\cdot G\cdot\cdots \cdot G\cdot G)=\sigma\hat\alpha(G\cdot G\cdot\cdots \cdot G\cdot G)=\alpha(G)^k$ and since $0<\sqrt[k]{\sigma}<\sigma$, we can get an approximation of $\alpha(G)$ that is better than $\sigma$ by $\sqrt[k]{\sigma\hat\alpha(G\cdot G\cdot\cdots \cdot G\cdot G)}=\alpha(G)$.

Comment: [Hardness of approximating independent set](http://aaronschild.wordpress.com/2012/12/16/hardness-of-approximating-independent-set/).  Recall that we often refer to _stable set_ as _independent set_.

Comment: This is too long and probably answers much more than the intended question. I only need an answer to inapproximability to constant factor and I believe there is a one step proof for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $G = K_2$, for which $\alpha(G)=1$.  The only product defined in terms of subgraphs of $K_4$ and for which $\alpha(G \times G) = 1$, is the strong product (⊠).  This doesn't quite work, since $\alpha(C_5 ⊠ C_5) = 5$, which is not a perfect square.

However, denoting the [lexicographic product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_product_of_graphs) by $\circ$, there is an easy proof due to Geller and Stahl that $\alpha(G \circ H) = \alpha(G)\alpha(H)$.

So you want the lexicographic product.

Comment: Is there any other graph product that is multiplicative in independence numbers?

Comment: @Turbo, that's a good question.  I'm not aware of any but also not aware of any reason there should not be one.